# What could be the problem with this array?

Tags: php, arrays

This is the source `$pData` array I have:

```
Array
(
    [code] => 105132
    [globalImages] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1148-1578-image_41ddeeef69eb94a8d9ccc1503d099810.jpg
        )

    [envImages] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1148-0-image_72e95c6424ec7bcd90994f1c0a3f4544.jpg
        )

    [attribs] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1578
                            [uniqCode] => 105132-1578
                            [parentId] => 0
                            [type] => Colour
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

When I call a value using the following (`line 337`):

```
<?php echo strtolower($pData['attribs'][0][0]['type']);?>
```

PHP Error log has the following line:

```
[13-Jan-2010 11:48:21] PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 0 in D:\apps\path\to\file\pages\product.php on line 337
```

What could I be doing wrong? As far as I see, there is nothing wrong with this simple call. May be someone see something fishy?

Thanks for any input!

### EDIT 01:

I forgot to say that the `echo` produces correct result. But it also makes the specified entry entry in the error log.

The `var_dump($pData['attribs'])` output:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>array(2) {
    [0]=>array(22) {
      ["id"]=>string(4) "1578"
      ["uniqCode"]=>string(11) "105132-1578"
      ["parentId"]=>string(1) "0"
      ["type"]=>string(6) "Colour"
      ["title"]=>string(5) "Beech"
      ["swatch"]=>string(22) "variant-437-swatch.jpg"
      ["width"]=>string(4) "1830"
      ["depth"]=>string(3) "610"
      ["height"]=>string(3) "740"
      ["floorToSeat"]=>string(1) "0"
      ["unit"]=>string(2) "mm"
      ["weight"]=>float(89)
      ["volume"]=>float(2.311)
      ["groupPack"]=>int(1)
      ["fobkl"]=>string(3) "407"
      ["br3"]=>string(3) "441"
      ["br2"]=>string(3) "467"
      ["br1"]=>string(3) "496"
      ["rcp"]=>string(3) "515"
      ["gwm"]=>string(3) "592"
      ["gem"]=>string(3) "618"
      ["images"]=>array(1) {
        [0]=>string(52) "1148-1578-image_41ddeeef69eb94a8d9ccc1503d099810.jpg"
      }
    }
    [1]=>array(22) {
      ["id"]=>string(4) "1577"
      ["uniqCode"]=>string(11) "105132-1577"
      ["parentId"]=>string(1) "0"
      ["type"]=>string(6) "Colour"
      ["title"]=>string(13) "Natural Maple"
      ["swatch"]=>string(22) "variant-436-swatch.jpg"
      ["width"]=>string(4) "1830"
      ["depth"]=>string(3) "610"
      ["height"]=>string(3) "740"
      ["floorToSeat"]=>string(1) "0"
      ["unit"]=>string(2) "mm"
      ["weight"]=>float(155.06)
      ["volume"]=>float(20.305)
      ["groupPack"]=>int(1)
      ["fobkl"]=>string(3) "407"
      ["br3"]=>string(3) "441"
      ["br2"]=>string(3) "467"
      ["br1"]=>string(3) "496"
      ["rcp"]=>string(3) "515"
      ["gwm"]=>string(3) "592"
      ["gem"]=>string(3) "618"
      ["images"]=>array(1) {
        [0]=>string(52) "1148-1577-image_9c4fc8337e5c106ea6b69863e68f54bb.jpg"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the array looks like you describe when you try to access the values? (just to make sure)

Comment: I `print_r` the array before the `echo` and have posted here.

Comment: That's because it's a `notice`, rather than an error - so the script continues

Comment: Please see my edited part of the question.

Comment: Try to go up from the `type` key, e.g. remove it, try, go up, try, go up, try, ... so you find out which index PHP cannot find

Comment: I tried `print_r($pData['attribs'][0])`. Same error.

Comment: could you also paste the output of var_dump($pData['attribs'][0][0]) in your question?

Comment: @Anurag - I have included it in my question.

Comment: No, there seems to be something wrong with the contents of $pData['attribs'] then. Try to var_dump this instead.

Comment: @Gordon: Please find the updated var_dump. Thanks.

Comment: The array looks perfectly alright. A debugger is your best bet to crack this, but I have a strong feeling that some other part of the code is tinkering with the array. Can you isolate your code to just the array? BTW, you should've seen two Notices if doing a var_dump and echo of the variable in question unless some other piece of code is accessing it that's not on line 337.

Comment: @Anurag: Yes, there are two notices. One for the `echo` and one for the `var_dump`. As you said, a debugger should be the best solution. Thank you for the sincere help!

Comment: great, let us know if you find anything interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A debugger can help to find the error, e.g. xdebug and [netbeans](http://netbeans.org/features/php/) as frontend.

Please verify that the source line in question really is `echo strtolower($pData['attribs'][0][0]['type'])`, e.g. by using an error handler like:

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline, $errcontext)
{
  if ( E_NOTICE===$errno && is_readable($errfile) ) {
    $source = file($errfile);
    for($i=max(0,$errline-4); $i<$errline+3; $i++ ) {
      if ( isset($source[$i]) ) {
        if ( $i+1===$errline ) {
          echo ' >>> ';
        }
        echo $source[$i];
      }
    }
  }

  return false;
}
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');
```

Comment: Thank you for the debugger suggestion. I shall go forward with it.

Answer (score 0):

Do your print_r on the row just before the echo, so you are sure that you see the array that your function actually work on. It could be a scoping problem (i.e., $pData is a local array in a function and you call echo outside that function).

Comment: Yes, I did `print_r` the array and that's what I have posted here. The funny thing is that the `echo` produces correct result, but also makes this entry in the error log!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong - the only possibility is that you defined one or both of the 0 keys as a string '0', making it an associative index (rather than numeric)

```
$pData['attribs']['0']['0']['type'] = 'Colour';
```

In which case you'd also need to refer to it as a string

Comment: I think PHP always converts "string" keys to "integers" when they only contain an integer value -- i.e. using the array index "15" is always seen as using the array index 15